# Is there a way to make a discord bot that sends a user a message the mentioned number of times?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I've been trying to make a discord bot with discord.py. I know how to make the bot send a message to the specified user, but I was wondering, is there a way to send the message a given number of times? If so, how can I do it?

As an example, if the user types **!dm @discorduser hello 5**, the bot will send "hello" to the specified user 5 times.

So far, my code is:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
print('Bot is ready.')


@client.command()
async def spam(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, content):
channel = await member.create_dm()
await channel.send(content)


client.run('bot token')
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my answer for the question, from my understanding you're trying to Direct Message a user x amount of times, and x can be changed depending on what the user wants.

```
@client.command()

# the arguments are: member, the amount of times you want to DM, and what you want to DM them.
async def spam(ctx, member : discord.Member, amount=1, content=None):

    # this loop will keep doing the script below the amount of 'amount' times.
    for i in range(amount):
        channel = await member.create_dm()
        await channel.send(content)
```